# Dynamic memory allocation in 2d array

Tags: c, malloc, scanf

The `scanf` statement is giving me trouble. I have tried `&arr[i][j]` and `(arr+i)+j` in place of `*(arr+i)+j`. However, this statement is still giving problems. Here is my code:

```
int **arr, m, n, i, j;
scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
arr = (int **) malloc( m * sizeof(int *) );

for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
  arr[m] = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));

for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
  for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    scanf("%d", *(arr + i) + j); //this statement

for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    printf("%d ", *(*(arr + i) + j));
  printf("\n");
}

getch();
return 0;
```

Comment: What about `(*arr)[i][j]` ?

Comment: Please show a simple example of input format.

Comment: @timrau firstly i want user to enter no of rows and column into m and n variables respectively, then i tried allocating memory for them. then user will enter numbers

Comment: @timrau yes i included <stdlib.h> as well

Comment: @timrau what's the root cause?

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/485088).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a severe typo:

```
  arr[m] = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Should be

```
  arr[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: i tried &arr[i][j] as well, its not working. my debugger stops at this statement. Is there something wrong with the way i m using malloc? looks like i m using the adresses in a wrong way

Comment: Since the way you call `malloc` looks fine, we need your input format to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Any message when your debugger stopped there? Is it waiting for your input?

Comment: error waa like:   Unhandled exception at 0x0f75effe in spiral.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcdcdcdcd.

Comment: firstly i want user to enter no of rows and column into m and n variables respectively, then i tried allocating memory for them. then user will enter numbers
input sample:
3
4
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
where 3 and 4 are no of rows and columns

Comment: @user3437973 Edited. Found the actual root cause.