# Reading the input to a two dimensional array created using malloc

Tags: c

`Dear friends,
I was trying to  define  a 2-D array named A using a dummy variable m through malloc.The variable A has been initialized to 0.
It is expected that new values get assigned to the matrix after the run .But that doesn't happen here.I would like to understand the correct way of doing this.I also tried method described in [dynamic memory allocation in 2d array and using scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508535/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-2d-array-and-using-scanf) and also avoided casting malloc.
Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
double** Allocate(int d1,int d2);
double** Allocate(int d1,int d2)
{  
  double **m;
  int i,j;
  m = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*d1);  
  for(i=0;i<d1;i++)
  {
    m[i]=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*d2);
  }
  for(i=0;i<d1;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<d2;j++)
    {
        m[i][j]=0.0;
    }
  }
  return m;
 }
 main()
{
int i,j;
int n=3;
float x[n],y[n];
double** A= Allocate(n,n);  
    for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
   {
    for(j=0;j<=n-1;j++)
    {
     scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
    }
  }
  for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
   {
    for(j=0;j<=n-1;j++)
    {
     printf("%f\t",A[i][j]);
    }printf("\n");
  }
 }
```

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`, and don't forget to check it for `NULL`.

Comment: `scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);` use `%lf`for double --> `scanf("%lf",&A[i][j]);`

Comment: Possibly a better way is to have *double Array[d1][d2];* followed by *double *ArrayPointer=malloc(d1*d2*sizeof(double)); * , and proceed from there.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart on modern systems, checking it for null guarantees nothingin particular.

Comment: @n.m. Care to elaborate? Are you suggesting we stop checking `malloc` result for `NULL`?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart no, but one should know that such checks do not always catch the out-of-memory condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are using the **wrong format specifier** for scanning a `double` type variable here :

  ```
  scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
          ^
  ```
- The correct format specifier is `%lf`, so instead scan this way into the array :

  ```
  scanf("%lf",&A[i][j]);
  ```

---

- You need not use `%lf` while using `printf()` because as [*@Robᵩ*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8747/rob%E1%B5%A9) suggested in the [*comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485509/reading-the-input-to-a-two-dimensional-array-created-using-malloc#comment64373637_38485755) :

> in `printf()`, `%f` is identical to `%lf`. Both accept a `double`

to know more, see this : [*click*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f)

---

- further, don't use `main()` as it is **not a valid signature for `main()`**, instead use `int main(void)`,because in standard C, the only valid signatures for main are:

  ```
  int main(void) //when arguments are not required
  ```
- And also,

  int main(int argc, char **argv) //when you require to send arguments

to know more, see this : [*click*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18928287/5281962)

---

- And always make sure to **free the malloced memory** at the end

  ```
    ..........  
       printf("%lf\t",A[i][j]);
      }printf("\n");
    }

    //freeing the malloced memory
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        free(A[i]);
    }
    free(A);

  }//end of main
  ```

---

Making above changes, your `main()` function would be :

```
int main(void)
{
    int i,j;
    int n=3;

    double** A= Allocate(n,n);

    for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=n-1;j++)
        {
            scanf("%lf",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=n-1;j++)
        {
             printf("%f\t",A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }

      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
          free(A[i]);
      }
      free(A);
 }
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct w.r.t. `scanf()`. But, in `printf()`, `%f` is identical to `%lf`. Both accept a `double`.